# In discord.py, How to allow a command from users with multiple roles

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord bot that checks for the user role by the command of:

`@commands.has_role("Lab Demonstrator")`

However, over the multiple servers, each has a slightly different roles setup and  I would like to check for whether they have permission "Lab Demonstrator" OR "Staff" OR "teacher"

I've tried
`@commands.has_role("Lab Demonstrator" OR "Staff")`

and has not been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `commands.has_any_role` decorator:

```py
@commands.has_any_role("Lab Demonstrator", "Staff", "Teacher")
async def ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking the roles solely to ensure that the member has the permissions, then in general this is not a good practice. You can instead use

```
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
...
@client.command(name='whatever')
@has_permissions(administrator=True) #or whichever permissions you want here
```

A couple of examples are `manage_webhooks`, `ban_members` and `create_instant_invite`. This ensures consistency of permissions even when role names, or the servers in question, are changed.